Using a Single API Gateway for Both Main and Nested Stacks in AWS SAM and CloudFormation
Details of the Problem:
I'm working on an AWS SAM project that involves a main stack (template.yml) and a nested stack (nestedTemplate.yml). Both stacks contain three Lambda functions each. My objective is to use a single API Gateway (AWS::Serverless::Api) to manage all six Lambda functions across these stacks.
I defined the API Gateway in the main stack and attempted to pass its ID to the nested stack as a parameter. However, when deploying, I encountered an error stating that the API Gateway must be created in the same stack as the resources it is associated with.
What I Tried:
I defined the API Gateway (AWS::Serverless::Api) in the main stack and passed the API ID to the nested stack as a parameter. The idea was to link the nested stack’s Lambda functions to this shared API.
What I Expected:
I expected to successfully use a single API Gateway across both the main and nested stacks, allowing all Lambda functions to be exposed under a unified API.
